# IOS Toolbarbutton item not triggering action with scroll bar

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I have done code for Scrollview(8images) + Toolbar as well. When I try to click the toolbar button item the scrollview is not turned back as expected. below is the code.

When I click Toolbar button, no action triggered to "IBAction clickprjinfo", I have confirm done "SentAction" to this IBACTION via Barbuttonitem in connection inspector.

during runtime, when i click hold toolbar button + touch on scroolview screen + then release button, then it trigger the IBACTION.

Anyone help to notify my mistake or better way to understand this.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self pgcontrolview];
}

-(void) pgcontrolview  {
   pageC.numberOfPages=8;
   pageC.currentPage=0;
   for (int i=1; i<=8; i++)
   {
       UIImageView *images=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",i]]];
       images.frame=CGRectMake((i-1)*1024, 0, 1024, 760);
       [scroller addSubview:images];
   }
   scroller.delegate=self;
   scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1024*8, 760);
   scroller.pagingEnabled=YES;

   UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle_Tap:)];
   tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

-(IBAction)clickprjinfo:(id)sender{
   pageC.currentPage=1;
   CGRect frame=scroller.frame;
   frame.origin.x=0;//frame.size.width*page;
   frame.origin.y=0;
   [scroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add Gesture delegate methods as below

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
// test if our control subview is on-screen
if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
    // we touched a button, slider, or other UIControl
    return NO; // ignore the touch
}
return YES; // handle the touch
}
```

Because it considering UIButton tapping as UITapGesture, so you don't need to allow UITapGesture on UIButton as the above delegate method ignore touch on UIControl (which in-turn UIButton) as allow to perform

`-(IBAction)clickprjinfo:(id)sender` action

Comment: Could you give bit extra, how do I use this method, you mean do I have to replace the method "handle_Tap" or where to call this method.

Comment: in .h file you need to add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate as          @interface DesignCordViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{}

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle_Tap:)];
    tap.delegate = self;
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

Comment: "handle_Tap" will be used to handle gesture recogniser where as -(IBAction)clickprjinfo:(id)sender is used to Barbuttonitem action

Comment: I have to add " tap.delegate = self" before the statement "[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap]". Then everything perfect.